# Error 403 Forbidden - when a site collection is locked as readonly

Tags: 2007, site-collection

I got an an error 403 Forbidden when I browse a site collection that I set to readonly (locked).

MOSS 2007 without SP2.

Is it related to SP2 installation ?

Answer (score 2):

Check in Central Administration > Application Management > Site Quotas and Locks if that site collection is set to lock itself when the quota is reached.